# ASP.NET MVC Redirect Non-WWW to WWW and Rewrite To Lowercase URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis-7

I'm trying to accomplish this using web.config and it worked fine when I had a default.aspx file but I'm using MVC and there's no root .aspx file. How can I get it to go to my home controller and then the index view?

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}"
           redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="convert to lower case" stopProcessing="false"> 
<match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false"/> 
<conditions> 
<!-- The following condition prevents rule from rewriting requests to .axd files --> 
<add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$"/> 
</conditions> 
<action type="Redirect" url="{toLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent"/> 
</rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
```

It was telling me that it cannot list the contents of the directory but that's not what it should be trying to do anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx this article?

Comment: I just did and it's pretty much the same thing I have up there. I republished it and now it works... Go figure.

Comment: I'm gonna' mark this as the answer though as it has some other things in here that could be of use to me as well. Thanks for that.